# How do I override a spark error message with my own unique description of the error

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using the following spark_reader method from SparkSession class DataProcessor

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def spark_reader(spark: SparkSession, options: dict) -> DataFrame:
        df = spark.read.load(**options)
        return df
```

When the folder it is reading from contain no parquet files, it throws the error message `AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.` but I want to change this to something more specific such as `folder contains no <file_type> files` - does anyone know how to change the error message?

I have tried to raise an exception within the spark_reader method but the Spark message is raised before it gets to the exception and throws the above mentioned error.

Comment: Use try except to catch the `AnalysisException` then raise your own exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is very basic you can do.

```py
    def spark_reader(spark: SparkSession, options: dict) -> DataFrame:
        try:
            df = spark.read.load(**options)
            return df
        except AnalysisException:
            print("folder contains no <file_type> files")
```